# Accounts have "Team Site" option disappearing

Tags: user-profile, user, user-accounts, team-sites

[image]I have invited all 354 stores that i manage and they all had the team site option to access the SharePoint, and now stores are losing the team site option through Office 365 is there any reason for this?

Regards,

Comment: Can you update your question with a screen shot so we can see what you are talking about?